# Magento 2 : what is use of _replica table in Magento_Catalog module?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, catalog, data-replication

As Magento releases 2.X version, I found `_replica` tables, particularly in the `Magento_Catalog` module may be for indexing the catalog data.

I also notice that `_replica` is nothing but the duplicate structure of the respective table in database nature but it means a lot for Magento 2 framework for read and write operational activities I guess.

I want to know that which operations Magento 2 application will consider for `_replica` tables for `Magento_Catalog`, `CatalogRule` and `CatalogInventory` module.

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Replica tables are mainly used for indexer optimization. Replica tables are used to prevent deadlocks or wait locks caused by read/write collisions on the same table.

In the above causes, Magento uses a separate table for reading and write operations and indexing. As a result of this switching process, customer can freely navigate to the category pages, search pages and user layered navigation pages filtered with price when you run full reindexing in the CLI.

If you feel my answer is correct and helps you, please accept and upvote it.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the people who upvoted for my answer.